# Htaccess files and url rewriting

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

*I have 2 questions.*

I am currently using wamp server to serve my website.

The homepage is 'localhost/prefix/index.php'

**Question 1:**

a. I would like it so my home page is:

```
'localhost/prefix/'
```

instead of

```
'localhost/prefix/index.php
```

b. I would like it so:

```
'localhost/prefix/admin/profile.php'
```

is

```
'localhost/prefix/admin/profile'
```

How do I go about doing this (I have googled and I am very confused by the syntax)?

**Question 2**

If I have a url like

```
'localhost/prefix/games?title=hi'
```

how can I make it so the url is like this:

```
'localhost/prefix/games/hi'
```

Thanks in advance!!
I really have got lost.

EDITED::///

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [R]
```

Is what I have so far.. It does nothing... But everyone says it should! (the htaccess file is doing something because if I do something random, it throws up errors).

EDITED::///

This seems to remove .php and index.php from the url:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /prefix/

# remove .php; use THE_REQUEST to prevent infinite loops
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301]


# remove index
RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1/ [R=301]

# remove slash if not directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301]

# add .php to access file, but don't redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]
```

Problem now is that my prefix base is not working so it ends up going to

```
localhost/something/something
```

rather than

```
localhost/prefix/something/something
```

Any ideas?

EDITED::///

I have sussed out that the above code actually works perfectly if the page i'm directing to is in a sub folder. so for example.. this will work:

```
localhost/prefix/admin/dashboard
```

But this (because the file is in the root directory, doesn't)

```
localhost/prefix/login.php
```

it redirects me to

```
localhost/login
```

Any ideas?

EDIT::///

If you are having problems getting it to work. close your browser down and restart... I had caching issues.

This code above will remove .php and also remove index.php.

Comment: So, at the moment, what happens if you go to `localhost/prefix`? Do you have any other `index.*`,`default.*` or `home.*` files in your root folder?

Comment: right ok. localhost/prefix directs correctly to index.php..

problem is that my links (that it would be a shame to have to change) are directing to localhost/prefix/index.php

so Question 1 a and b are very similar in such that I just want to knock the .php off the end. But also that I want to know how to knock index.php off the end if it is localhost/prefix.

make sense?......... I also have many .php files in the root. directory like login.php etc. which need to be localhost/prefix/login

Comment: If `localhost/prefix/index.php` exists, I really don't see the problem of having `hrefs` that link to it...

Comment: I like how wordpress lays its url's out and wanted to copy this.

Comment: But, your `hrefs` are **already** linking to `index.php` - URL rewriting is (afaik) only for rewriting URLs that you link to; for example, if you wanted to rename your `index.php` to `another-file.php`, you could use mod_rewrite to prevent the need to change all your links, but `index.php` would still be what would be shown in the address bar, because that's what the `href` said! (I am no total expert though, and would be happy to be proved wrong if anyone else knows how to do it)

Comment: Got it working... Just needed to close browser and re-open. cached it like a git.